# log out happens before db operation Kotlin KMM Realm Mongodb

Tags: kotlin, realm, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a kmm app, and I have a shared repository in Kotlin.
I have a login that does the normal login to Realm MongoDb and add a FCM key.
I have also a logout method that should remove first the FCM token and then do the logOUT() from Realm MongoDB

My logOut method:

```
suspend fun doLogout(token: String) {
    val userId = appService.currentUser?.id

    realm.write {

            var user = query<UserInfo>("_id = $0", userId).first().find()
            if (user != null) {
                val productIndex =
                    user.FCMToken.withIndex().findLast { it.value == token }!!.index

                user = findLatest(user)!!.also {
                    it.FCMToken.removeAt(productIndex)
                }
                copyToRealm(user)
            }        
    }

    appService.currentUser?.logOut()
}
```

I think what happens is that the logout happens before the DB change.

How can I do the logout after the db change is completed?

Comment: `realm.write {` this is an asynchronous call - the code following the closure `{...}` could potentially execute before the code in the closure. Move the `.logout` right after the `copyToRealm`

Comment: If I do that I get the error, `Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body`

Comment: @Jay How I can avoid this? I  am new to Kotlin :)

Comment: There are a lot of resources here on SO and the internet of how to address that error. See [Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Suspension+functions+can+be+called+only+within+coroutine+body).

Comment: Any easy way, or do I need to change all my code?

Comment: The code needs to be updated to handle asynchronous functions.